# Google Map not displaying in right aligned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

In my html code I have two div,I want to display my map in my right aligned 65% div. I have tried setting each map's parents height to 100% and also followed the style in the documentation, then also I am not able to display the map Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/1w5u3t8y/

```css
.row {
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 35%;
  background: #2193b0;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 65%;
}

.card {
  width: 450px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(#f8f8f8, #fff);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:100%;">
  <div class="column left" />
  <div class="column right" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="card" id="mapwrapper" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="card-header">
        Add your Location
        <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-info float-right ml-3" onclick="submitloc()">Save My Location</a> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" style="width:300px;" id="location-text-box" placeholder="Enter place to search">
      </div>
      <div id="map" style="height:100%; width:65%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the JavaScript that you use to initialise the map. Don't include your API key.

Comment: @Turnip I added the jsfiddle link, I wasn't able to add the js code due to limit

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your HTML and CSS below. I have implemented Flexbox which helps solves your layout issues. We will also need to see your Google Maps JavaScript in order to test.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column left">
    </div>
    <div class="column right">
        <div class="card" id="mapwrapper">
            <div class="card-header">
                Add your Location
                <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-info float-right ml-3" onclick="submitloc()">Save My Location</a> -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" style="width:300px;" id="location-text-box" placeholder="Enter place to search">
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}

.left {
    flex: 1 1 35%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #2193b0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
}

.right {
    flex: 1 1 65%;
    background-color: grey;
 }

.card {
    width: 450px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(#f8f8f8, #fff);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/eYmVXQy)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have updated with js script. I want the second div to be a card which contains map, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit closer to what you wanted? I had to shuffle around your `div#map` to be in the right spot (for painting order, and added background for visibility), if I understand correctly.

The reason it's not lining up, is cause of other border factors, and so I:

- Added a [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property to your CSS
- Moved the `position:relative` to your `div.column`
- Moved the "position:absolute`from`div#map`to your`div.card`
- Added `top` and `bottom` anchors to `div.card` to simulate `height: 100%` without overflow.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;               /* Added */
  box-sizing: border-box;           /* Added */
}

.left {
  width: 35%;
  background: #2193b0;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 65%;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;             /* Added */
  width: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(#f8f8f8, #fff);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  bottom: 0;                     /* Added */
  top: 0;                        /* Added */
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  /*position: absolute;          /* Removed */
  background-color: pink;        /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:100%;">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column right">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="card" id="mapwrapper">
      <div class="card-header">
        Add your Location
        <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-info float-right ml-3" onclick="submitloc()">Save My Location</a> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" style="width:300px;" id="location-text-box" placeholder="Enter place to search">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```